# To change the background color and slider color of a trackbar and make the background transparent

Tags: vb.net, trackbar

I want to change the color of the slider (cursor) and the color of the line on which the slider lies. I also want to make the background transparent.

I used this code in the control's constructor but it still gives me a white background.

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True) 
Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's the background color of the parent object?  What is the parent object?

Comment: Too little info.  If you are playing with the standard NET TrackBar, how did you put anything in the ctor?  Are you saying you sub classed it? The std one already adopts the Parent control BackColor so whats the point of Transparent BG? Some of those other things in your "I-want" list may be hard to do using the TrackBar as a starting point as it already inherits from `ScrollBar`.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 the background is an image. The trackbar lies on the form.

Comment: @Plutonix I am playing with the standard NET trackbar. Also, when i put the code in the subclass it didnt do anything. What do you suggest? Can i use the scrollbar to act like a trackbar and then make those changes? Or do you think i should make a custom trackbar? If so could you give me a starting point for that?

Comment: @Plutonix Hey, is there a way to change the size of the cursor on the Trackbar? Please help me out with this :X

Comment: This "image" that is in the background, is it the background image of the form or is it an image in a `PictureBox` or something similar? As for customizing the "cursor" (I'm guessing you mean the thumb, i.e. the thing you drag), you most likely cannot do that without creating a custom control.

Comment: @VisualVincent Its the background image of the form. Oh okay then, custom control it is.